# Why can I not interact with my buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `ViewController` that holds six buttons. Each of the buttons has `.tag`s 1 through 6 and are all hooked up to the same `IBAction` that uses the `.tag` to figure out what to do. Everything works great on the 4 inch device.

On the 3.5 in device, however, I need to re-arrange the buttons to make things fit. I tried to just retrieve the buttons using `[self.view viewWithTag: tag]` and change the retrieved buttons's `.frame` but that just doesn't seem to do anything. Therefore, I did the following:

```
-(void) rearrangeButtons
{
    int space  = 7;  // space between the first button and the left side of the screen as well as between individual buttons

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // Get the button and remove from superview:
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag: i+1];
        [button removeFromSuperview];

        // Resize its width and height:
        UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        newButton.frame = CGRectMake(space + (i*(button.frame.size.width/2)) + (i*space), 170, button.frame.size.width/2, button.frame.size.height/2);
        newButton.tag = button.tag;

        //[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightButtonWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [newButton targetForAction:@selector(highlightButtonWithTag:) withSender:newButton];

        [newButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i", i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view addSubview: newButton];
    }
}
```

This removes the buttons and places them with new buttons. Arranging them works fine. However, the selector I want to be called isn't called and I can't seem to manipulate properties of the buttons as I was able to do with the buttons I did before (even though that was also purely based on their tags.

```
- (IBAction) selectIcon:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    // "Un"highlight previous button
    UIButton *prevButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag: self.selectedIcon];
    prevButton.highlighted = NO;

    // Highlight tapped button:
    self.selectedIcon = sender.tag;
    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButtonWithTag:) withObject:@(self.selectedIcon) afterDelay:0];
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: hello Florian you are craeting new button "
        // Resize its width and height:
        UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];" for changing frame you simply write button.frame=cgrectmake(put frame).no need to create another button

Comment: Hey - thanks for your reply! I don't quite see how your code differs from the code I posted, though. I am using `buttonWithType:` to create a `UIButton` and then set its `.frame` property like you suggest. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new button instance, try to use the existing one that is defined with the tag. In this case you don't have to add and remove the button from the superview. Just reuse them and set frame on those button like this

```
-(void) rearrangeButtons
{
    int space  = 7;  // space between the first button and the left side of the screen as well as between individual buttons

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag: i+1] ;
        if(newButton == nil) {
            newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
            newButton.tag = i+1;
            [self.view addSubview: newButton];
        }
        newButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, i*(i+1) *20, 50, 50);
        [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectIcon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
       // [newButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i", i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [newButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
- (IBAction) selectIcon:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    // "Un"highlight previous button
    UIButton *prevButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag: self.selectedIcon];
    prevButton.highlighted = NO;

    // Highlight tapped button:
    self.selectedIcon = sender.tag;
    [self highlightButtonWithTag:self.selectedIcon];
}

-(void)highlightButtonWithTag:(NSInteger) selectedIcon
{
    NSLog(@"highlightButton at position: %ld", (long)selectedIcon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. As I said in my question, I have tried just trying to adjust the `.frame` property of the `UIButton` I retrieved using `viewWithTag:` but that doesn't change the buttons at all.

I tried again using your code - still no luck, though.

Comment: Are you still using the code to add/ remove the button from superview? you just have to do it once when the newButton is null

Comment: Nope. I just replaced everything in my for loop with the equivalent of the code you posted.

Comment: i updated the answer with the code that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use addTarget:action:forControlEvents:  ?

```
[newButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(highlightButtonWithTag:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```